# Extracting replies from Yahoo Finance Forum

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape comments from the Yahoo Finance conversation page (e.g. [TSLA](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/community?p=TSLA)) using Python Selenium. I would like to extract all comments together with their replies. As Yahoo Finance does not automatically show all the replies under each comment and have no unique identifier for individual comment, there are also problems of deleted comments, what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll inspect the network tab, you'll notice the API that the client communicates with to fetch the comments and related data. It required some data like `spotId` and `uuid`. I guess this is to identify the article.
With this information, you can simply use BeautifulSoup and requests to make the process much more efficient and faster than using Selenium.
Some example code:

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/community?p=TSLA'
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#spotim-config').get_text(strip=True))['config']

url = "https://api-2-0.spot.im/v1.0.0/conversation/read"
payload = json.dumps({
  "conversation_id": data['spotId'] + data['uuid'].replace('_', '$'),
  "count": 250,
  "offset": 0
})
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'x-spot-id': data['spotId'],
  'x-post-id': data['uuid'].replace('_', '$'),
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
data = response.json()
```

Since the API is paginated, play around with the values of `count` and `offset`  to get subsequent pages.

Comment: This is amazing! I didn't know there is a way to get the comments through API, and it appears to save the hustle of loading comments and definitely solve the identifier problem. Would it be able to record the post time as well?

Comment: All the data that you’re seeing on the frontend is sourced through this call. Take a look at the JSON returned, I’m sure you’ll find what you’re looking for.

Comment: I originally didn't recognise the time format, but now was able to find a way to convert it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the website ([TLSA](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/community?p=TSLA)), I'd say it is possible to accomplish what you want. How I would approach it is utilizing the structure of the comment section.

The list elements of the section make it easy to scarp with driver.get_elements() in selenium.

[image: list elements]

A sample of getting all the list elements would follow something along these lines:

```
textList = []
comment_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'spcv_list-item')

for i in range(len(comment_elements)):
    textList.append(comment_elements[i].text)
print(textList)
```

I think this is what you're looking for. The totaility of the Li element's (or comment element) text will be scraped then appended to the total list of text. The only caveat to this method is it seems the site does not load all 38,000+ comments at once (I wonder why... haha), so you're probbaly going to have to do a while loop that clicks the button until it can't click anymore. In code, that 'll probably look like:

```
while (true):
    try:
        sleep(4) # waits for comments to load after each click
        more_comments = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'load-more-messages')
        more_comments.click()
    except:
        break
```

Finally, this looks a lot like the [video](https://youtu.be/IU0QtIAwkxw) I watched when I first was learning selenium. He had the same problem/setup but with flights on a website. Also, he used BS4 along with selenium which may be a better solution than what I gave, so I would check it out.

Hope I gave some insight and have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for the response! It is similar to what I have in mind, but for some reason, I don't seem to be able to get the comments using find_element with the corresponding tags even after switching to iframe.